# Getting a cleaner GC Peak Resolution

Tags: chromatography

I have a GC with a peak pair I'm interested in separating but are not getting resolved cleanly at the moment. Any tips on what temperature programming tweaks might help me?

The problem pair elutes at about 3.3 mins. The temp program was 120 C for 2 min followed by a 8 C/min ramp to 180 C & a final hold of 5 min.

Changing the column, detector or carrier gas is not an option. I want to just get the best I can by temp. programming optimization.

I've tried isothermal runs at 120 & 100 C but not much help. The peaks still come unseparated.

Since it is just this two peaks that interest me mostly, theoretically a ramp is superfluous isn't it? Just figuring out the right isothermal run ought to give me the separation of interest?

Edit:

The column is an OV-351 packed col. 2 m long and 1/8" in diameter. N2 carrier gas with FID. The molecules are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give any more details about the column/setup you're using, and the molecules you're trying to separate?

Comment: Try diluting your compounds.

Comment: You could also try derivatisation

Comment: If time is not an issue. Go for an isotherm at low temperature.

Comment: @QuantumCAPUCCINO Yep, time's not an issue. I'll try isothermals at 70 / 80 / 90 / 100 C.  What Temp. would you try? Any others? Even lower?

Comment: I would look at literature to be honest. If not trial and error going from high to low. You could also try adjusting the carrier flow.

Comment: Is it possible heat during the ramp or even in the injector is causing a rearrangement of the epoxide to the aldehyde?

Comment: 2m seems short for a column. Is it 20m?

Comment: @Beerhunter Maybe. I can try. That would help by making the BPs further apart? Or.....?

Comment: @Beerhunter It was a packed column. Not  a capillary column.

Comment: Are you measuring relative amounts via GC, i.e., checking for reaction completion?

Answer (score -1):

I just thought that the rearrangement might be occurring during the analysis I.e. The thermal ramp, implying a lower temperature would be better for you. The bp of each compound is too close to separate purely in that way.